# Getting elements from an array with contents from decode json

Tags: php, arrays, json

It's sort of hard to describe the question in the title, but I will explain it in the body. So I have this example JSON (It's similar to the one I have):

```
[{"AssetId":234234,"Name":"Test1"},{"AssetId":53453,"Name":"Test2"}]
```

So basically I want to get the AssetId element from the first array of the main array. I am calling this in PHP, but it isn't working

```
$array = json_decode("[{"AssetId":234234,"Name":"Test1"},{"AssetId":53453,"Name":"Test2"}]");
echo $array[0][0]
```

So I guess that would be the first array in the main array to get AssetId of the element with the Name of Test1. Any help on getting it?

Comment: https://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php check documentation about json decode

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the double quotes with single quotes, your attempt will lead to parse error of unexpected T_STRING

Instead of this

```
$array = json_decode("[{"AssetId":234234,"Name":"Test1"},{"AssetId":53453,"Name":"Test2"}]");
                     ^
```

Try this:

```
$array = json_decode('[{"AssetId":234234,"Name":"Test1"},{"AssetId":53453,"Name":"Test2"}]');
foreach($array as $arr){
  echo $arr->AssetId;
}
```

Comment: It was just an example, it's not my real json. I got it to work, but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

what about echo $array[0]->AssetId

edit :

```
$json = json_decode('[{"AssetId":234234,"Name":"Test1"},{"AssetId":53453,"Name":"Test2"}]');
echo $json[0]->AssetId;
```

works here

Comment: "AssetId":234234 => "AssetId":"234234"