# Parse JSON using gson with key name containing period (.)

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

```
{
   "data.url" : "http://dev.com",
   "value": [
       {
         "color": "red"
          "shape": "rect"
       },
       {
          "color": "blue"
          "shape": "rect"
       }
   ]
}
```

Tried using gson.json, but `.` character is blocking from creating class,
Is there a way to remap the dotted field?

Comment: `$arr = json_decode('yourvar'); echo $arr[0]->value[0]->color;` don't work for value part?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav this isn't PHP

Comment: @BrianRoach, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273938/getting-elements-from-an-array-with-contents-from-decode-json look this answer. I used same. This is not php too? Exaplain please

Comment: @SharikovVladislav **This question has nothing to do with PHP**. It's a question about Java and using Gson.

Comment: @BrianRoach ok :) sorry now :)

Answer (score 5):

Because Java doesn't allow `.` in a variable name, you need to use the `@SerializedName` annotation on that field in your class:

```
public class MyPojo {

    @SerializedName("data.url")
    private String dataUrl;
    ...

}
```